# Polygon smoothing

Tags: geometry, 2d

I want to "smoothen" polygons so that they remain most of their "outer" appearance, but removed of "inner corridors".

To put it into context: The picture below shows a polygons that have been created out of a set of multiple points. The polygons below represent roughly a room, and those inwards parts of each polygon were once doors and other things. 
Now I want to re-improve these polygons, so they look again like rooms.

My question is: What (set of) algorithm(s) fits my needs? Creating a convex hull or bufer polygon is not what I want (though I tried). Buffer polygons do not keep the outer appearance of the polygons, and convex hulls don't remove these inwards parts.

That's what it looks like:
[image: Polygons]
And this is a badly photoshopped image of what I want it to look like. 
Notice the small inner corridors are removed.

[image: Fixed room polygons]

Edit: Common simplification also won't work, probably. This is how my polygons simplified with Douglas Peucker look like. The distance tolerance is aggressive already, but the inner dents are still not gone. This is not surprising and quite expected, since the inner dents are long.

[image: Simplified polygons]

Edit 2:

It's like I want to remove the inner dent of this example:

[image: B]

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking goes under the phrase *polygon simplification*, on which there is a vast literature.
A start can be found [at this link](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/files/simplifying-polygons.shtml),
from which the below images are copied.

---

[image] [image]

---

There are many sophisticated algorithms aimed at achieving particular optimization criteria,
many surveyed in the 
[*Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry*](https://www.crcpress.com/Handbook-of-Discrete-and-Computational-Geometry-Second-Edition/Toth-ORourke-Goodman/p/book/9781584883012).

Comment: I don't think polygon simplification will help. I've updated my question with an example with Douglas Peucker applied. In the example picture you posted, my problem is like I want to remove the dent of the "good looking" B in the middle of the right side of the B.

Comment: I've updated my question with your posted picture to illustrate this.

Comment: @benjist: I see. You need an ad hoc "dent detector," specific for your type of input polygons. They have a very particular inner angle profile, with prominent reflex vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "dents" (as in your "edit 2") can be done with methods that operate on a per-pixel level, called "mathematical morphology". The wikipedia webpage [1] is well explained, take a look in particular at the *opening* and *closing* operations that may fit your needs.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology